# pandas - How to show whole numbers along with floats?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have this list:

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame([1, 2.321, 13.3444, 7.5, 5])
```

How can I make the output table show whole numbers without decimal places and others with, say 2, decimal places? Something like this:

```
1 2.30 13.34 7.50 5
```

instead of this:

```
1.00 2.30 13.34 7.50 5.00
```

Comment: You should not try to control float format, **unless** you're willing to convert to string, or settle for a fixed format (see second/third duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you dont want to change the numbers themselves but only the way they are presented, this is the way to go:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)
```

In case you want to change the underlying numbers, there is a round function that can be applied to DataFrames or columns, such as

```
df.round(2)  # two decimals
```

Comment: I ended up with `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: f'%.{0 if x.is_integer() else 1}f' % x)`